# how to determine changes belonging to same changelist in perforce while diffing?

Tags: perforce, comments

Is there a way to determine if two differences between two versions of a file belong to same or different changelist ? 
If not, then would it be a good practice to mention the changelist numbers in the comments when the changes are made ?

Comment: As it stands, this question makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but the visual client has a Time-Lapse View for a file that will tell you which revision introduced a particular change, and you can scrub that back through revisions as well to find out earlier changes if needed.